# Python 3: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'

Tags: python

I have a txt split by lines. Each line contains an IPv6 address. I have to check if a line has 18 zeros in it, and if it has then I have to write it to a file. But my code doesn't work.

```
i = 0
j = 0
nullak = 0
with open('sok.txt', 'w') as kiiras:
    for sor in cimek:
        aktualis = list(cimek[i])
        for nullak in aktualis:
             if aktualis[j] == 0:
                 nullak += 1
             j += 1
        if int(nullak) >= 18:
            kiiras.write('{0}. {1}'.format(i+1, cimek[i]))
        i += 1
        nullak = 0
        j = 0
```

I get the error 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'' in line 'if int(nullak) >= 18:'. Why?

Comment: It means that `nullak` has a value of `d`, not a numeric value.  Try printing `aktualis` to double-check its contents before iterating over it.

Comment: But nullak is zero from the begining and if a find a zero a just add one to nullak. So it cannot contain a 'd', I think.

Comment: `for nullak in aktualis` overwrites `nullak`.

Comment: Thanks, that was why I got the error, but it still doesn't write anything in the file. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just string logic:

```
int(nullak) >= 18
```

becomes:

```
nullak.count('0') >= 18
```